# Cast Map including Collections

Tags: java

Code below seems to work casting `map_b` to `map_a`, but is there a better solution?

```
Map<Integer,List<MyClass>> map_a =  new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer,List<Object>> map_b = factory.createMapWithMyClasses();

for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Object>> entry : map_b.entrySet())
{
    map_a.put(entry.getKey(), (List<MyClass>) (List) entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` instead of `Object`.

```
Map<Integer,List<MyClass>> map_a =  new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer,List<?>> map_b = factory.createMapWithMyClasses();
for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<?>> entry : map_b.entrySet()){
    map_a.put(entry.getKey(), (List<MyClass>) entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: OK, it looks better, but does it change anything crucially?   I want some code on one line.

Comment: @jiri463 how would having things on "one line" make it better? or change anything? I think you need to clarify to the question what is it you actually want